# ASP .NET MVC Ajax Request Internal server Error?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

just trying to learn ajax on asp.net mvc,but dont know whats wrong with it?

my controller class method=>

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Getdata(string batchcode)
    {
        ///var studentid = db.Studentassignbatches.Where(x => x.batch_code == batchcode).Select(x => new Studentassignbatche { UserId = x.UserId }).ToList();
        return Json("hi",JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    }
```

and my view and ajax request>

```
<select onchange="ShowBatchCode()" id="BatchList" class="form-control input-lg">
        <option class="pull-left" value="CCNA Security-1">CCNA Security-1</option>
        <option class="pull-left" value="CCNA Security-2">CCNA Security-2</option>
        <option class="pull-left" value="JNCSP-SEC-1">JNCSP-SEC-1</option>
        <option class="pull-left" value="Oracle Database 12c-1">Oracle Database 12c-1</option>
</select>
```

and ajax=>

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowBatchCode() {
    var batchcode = $('#BatchList').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: 'Getdata',
        data: { batchcode: batchcode },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('Something Went Wrong!');
        }
    });
}
```

and it always show me a alert "Something Went Wrong!".so i debug my web page and i found=>
[image]

505 Internal server Error.i dont know how to solve it.and try to remove
[Httppost] and also try use

```
 data: batchcode,
```

but nothing works for me.help me please?anybody!!!!!

Comment: contentType: 'application/json', , you need change data to json

Comment: data: JSON.stringify({ batchcode: batchcode })

Comment: Try giving controller name if name is YourController then then url should be 'Your/Getdata'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have indicated:

```
contentType: 'application/json',
```

but you sent `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` here:

```
data: { batchcode: batchcode },
```

So either get rid of the `contentType: 'application/json'` line or make sure that you are sending JSON to the server:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ batchcode: batchcode }),
```

Comment: Not Working For ME!

Comment: What is the exact response body from the server? You can see it from the developer toolbar in your browser.

Comment: That's not the response body sent from the server. Could you please show the exact HTML returned by the server as a response to the AJAX call? Just click on the AJAX call in your developer toolbar and look at the response tab.

Comment: hope this will help you?

Comment: OK, you are getting 404 Not Found. So it looks like your `url` parameter is wrong. Try specifying the correct url to your controller action.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143608/discussion-between-nayan-chowdhury-and-darin-dimitrov).